# Application is not supported in a Windows App project

Tags: windows-store-apps, xamarin, visual-studio-2013

I don't know when and how this happened, but every time I open an existing Windows Store app in Visual Studio 2013, I get "... is not supported in a Windows App project." error messages for all standard xaml tags in App.xaml and ...Page.xaml files.

Since there's not much to find yet when googling this, I think it's worth asking a question here to see if someone else has had this problem and maybe found a solution for it.

Comment: Got a tip on twitter to delete .suo files. That fixed the problem, but the problem is back next time the solution is opened because a new .suo file exists. Need to investigate what part of the .suo file that makes the problem appear.

Comment: Here is reproduction steps for the problem. It has to do with the Xamarin plugin for Visual Studio. http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/10296/ton-of-intellisense-issues-w-vs2013-latest-stable-release-resharper#latest

Comment: After uninstalling Xamarin, I'm again able to work with Windows Store apps. I'm also able to edit project properties without getting error messages. Hope Xamarin will fix this issue and provide a solution soon.

Comment: Same problem for me where VS gives an error for each element in your XAML files: [element] is not supported in a windows app project. Luckely i can still edit files in Blend which does not have this problem at all. For now the only solution seems waiting for Xamarin to fix this.

Comment: After uninstalling just Xamarin Shell,all errors disappeared.

Comment: I have the exact same problem - clean install of VS and Blend, and no Xamarin what so ever. Using Prism and Unity for WinRT.

Answer (score 0):

I've never had this issue before, but this sounds like a reference issue. This is the kind of error you would get when using WPF or Silverlight controls in a Windows Store application. Make sure that the project is currently referencing the ".NET for Windows Store apps" and the "Windows" assembly. It should not reference the "WindosBase" or "Windows Phone" assembly.

Comment: It happens to a file -> new project too. When I close the solution and reopen it, the XAML editor complains about every regular tag for Windows Store apps.